# Why does ElasticSearch use "must" and "should" rather than the more conventional boolean names "and"/"or"?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a semantic difference between `should` and `or`? Or some engineering reason?

For example, I could imagine that it could help make an ElasticSearch query look different from a query in another search language.

Understanding the design decision would guide me in the intended uses of the query language.

Comment: `should` has the `minimum_should_match` attribute which is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Must and should are more comfortable to build complex boolean logic query. If you have to build only simple queries and you want to use and and or operators you could use query string query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html . I suggest to take a look here, that is explained the use of must should operators https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query